# Scroll View: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make call a method from another class when a button is pressed, but it is not working and giving a fatal error (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value). I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code from the first class (FirstViewController)

```
@IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton) {
        SecondViewController().pressedButton()
    }
```

Here's the code in another class (SecondViewController)

```
func pressedButton() {
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 320, y: 0), animated: true)
    }
```

I placed the above code right after `viewDidLoad` (Within SecondViewController's class).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your first code `SecondViewController()` creates a whole new SecondViewController instance. That is not the same SecondViewController that has a `scrollView`, so its `scrollView` is nil and you crash when you try to use it.

Instead, a SecondViewController needs to exist *already* in your view controller hierarchy, and you need to talk to *that* SecondViewController.

Comment: On this distinction, see the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECinstanceRefs

Comment: How do I do that in Swift? Am I supposed to make the instance like a property?